# comparing data between two tables

Tags: database, r

I have two tables of data:
Table `A` contains traffic accidents and table `B` contains some points on road (for example crossroads).

My idea is to create square areas around points from group `B` and find accidents from group `A` which happened in these areas.

I am using KROVAK coordinates, so example is:

```
Step 1: take point from group B with coo. (X=1800050 Y=6000050)
Step 2: create square area around this point (a=50m)
    Area size is: X=(1800000 ; 1800100)
                  Y=(6000000 ; 6000100)
Step 3: is point from group A in this area(is X and Y belong in this interval) ?
```

And finally my question: Is possible to compare data between this two tables (group `A`, group `B`) in R? And can anyone give me some advice how to do that interval compare across two tables? Thanks a lot. :-)  evz

Comment: Are you asking for a SQL command that returns certain results?  Just saying you want "to compare data" between two tables leaves a lot to the Reader's imagination.

Comment: You've used the `database` tag for your question. Are the "tables" you speak of database tables (if so, in what type of database?) or R variables?

Comment: Yes, I am asking for SQL command which compare data between two tables and if this data belong in same area i want to copy ID from group B in new column in table A. (in one area can happen many accidents and one accident can happen only in one area)

Comment: R has several mechanisms for working with table using SQL syntax. Try installing the `sqldf` library, loading it and working through the examples. This will be a `join` operation with a calculated "where" condition using two conditions. I'm thinking that the downvotes are people who are unhappy that you provided no data examples to do any testing.

Comment: The "new column" in table A should be added (to every record!) as a first step, leaving the value Null or some "magic value" that means the record has never been updated from table B.  Please give the tables' data definitions, at least for the columns that are relevant to this task. A SQL `update` query can then be formulated that sets the "new column" in table A to your required value from table B.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with sqldf. If you look at example 11 in https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_4._Join you see two database tables being joined by a calculated field that uses proximity:

```
seqdf <- data.frame(thetime=seq(100,225,5),thevalue=factor(letters))
boundsdf <- data.frame(thestart=c(110,160,200), theend=c(130,180,220), groupID=c(555,666,777))
testquery_1 <- sqldf("select seqdf.thetime, seqdf.thevalue, boundsdf.groupID 
from seqdf left join boundsdf on (seqdf.thetime <= boundsdf.theend) and (seqdf.thetime >= boundsdf.thestart)")
```

I modified it so that it uses a single calculated field to join with a table with a single location field:

```
boundsdf2 <- data.frame(loc = c(120,170,210), groupID=boundsdf$groupID)
testquery_2 <- sqldf("select seqdf.thetime, seqdf.thevalue, boundsdf2.groupID 
from seqdf left join boundsdf2 on ( abs(seqdf.thetime-boundsdf2.loc) <=10 ) ")
 #-----------
 > identical(testquery_2, testquery_1)
 [1] TRUE
```

So you should be able to use the same strategy with two conditions on lat and long (or any grid system shared by both dataframes for accident location.